# Windows Server 2003 R2 - Adaptec Storage Manager email notification not working

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, raid, adaptec

I'm having problems with the Adaptec storage Manager email notification. It can't send emails to recipients, always showing an ERROR message.
Seems that the problem it's related to some java voodoo certificate magic, but I'm not sure.

Looking at the SMTPErr.log it throws:

> ERROR: can not send SMTP message in secure connection
>
> javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP
>   host;
>   nested exception is:    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I really don't understand what is the problem and why the Adaptec Storage Manager email notification don't run out-of-the-box.

I'm using a www.gmx.com email account. The smtp server data is mail.gmx.com, and port 25 or 587.

I don't know if it's related, but using Internet Explorer 7 can't open https:\www.gmx.com, with an error like "Can't show this page".
Surfing on the web, seems that Windows Server 2003 don't has support for SHA2 certificates. Seems that I need a Kb update.

Also, I can send an email thru GMX using Outlook Express.
I'm using Adaptec Storage Manager version 7.31.00 (18856).

Thanks for your help-

Comment: I use and used many, many Adaptec controllers and never had any problems. The error message describes a certificate error...do you maybe use SSL / TLS encryption (or similar) in your email-server? You should also mention the used email-server in your question.

Comment: Port 587 is (usually) used to send mails from authenticated clients. I suppose your ASM is none. Could you try and setup your GMX account to use default SMTP values and without authentication and try again?

Comment: Using default port 25 can't send email notification also.

Comment: Have you ever been able to successfully relay an email via GMX? Without the ASM, I mean. And what version of ASM are you using?